# Why Use Storyboards for Upcoming iPhone 6's Larger Screen? Difference?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, screen

I've read around that Apple is hinting to developers at a larger-screen iPhone by pushing developers to use Storyboard and auto-layout.  I understand why auto-layout would be useful, to organise items according to screen size, but what do Storyboards have to do with anything?

I may be missing an obvious advantage (in relation to larger screens), so any help would be much appreciated.  :)

Comment: This question is pointless unless you can point to a real Apple reference indicating that Storyboards should be used over other solutions. And there is nothing coming from Apple that makes any suggestion that the next iPhone will have a larger screen. It may or may not. It's all just guessing and theory at this point.

Comment: You are perhaps misquoting a little. In order to develop a GUI that will adapt to the various screen sizes constraints could (or arguably should) be used. You can easily add and manage constraints within a Storyboard so that would be why the use of Storyboards might be encouraged. However its not necessary, you can add constraints programatically and thus there is no requirement to use storyboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A**. You say that there are some notice from Apple about the larger screen of the iPhone6: **This is impossible because Apple doesn't release any information until the date of Keynotes and WWDC.**

**B**. You can or not use *Storyboard*, and you can or not use *AutoLayout*: **the 2 things are separate** because you can also use *AutoLayout* in `nib` or `programmatically`.

**C**. What **developers don't know**, is that `Storyboard` are just a **market move**. I spoken directly with a my friend engineer in Apple about this and the information is real. The reason is also obvious. Is not the topic to speak about this but you can search on google and you will find a lot of information about the advantages to don't use storyboard. 
Yes, **storyboard are easy**, but **are not developer friendly if you think to work in a serious project with a big team**. In a team you can use `GIT`, you can use `shared repositories`, you can `export a part of code with the interface`...in all this thing, *Storyboard* are **BAD**!

So i encourage developers to **DON'T USE** `storyboard` and use at max **NIB** file, or write the UI directly by **code**.

Answer (score 1):

There currently doesn't appear to be any advantage to using storyboards versus XIBs or programmatic layout as far as multiple screen sizes are concerned. Auto-layout is definitely advantageous as it allows you to define your interface elements in relation to each other (and the screen), as opposed to using fixed numerical values for location and size. This would allow the UI to then easily adapt to varying screen sizes and aspect ratios.

The only potential reason storyboards could become useful for multiple screen sizes in the future is if Apple adds functionality to them to allow you to define entirely separate views based on device/screen size. So for example, they might make it easy to show a view with an extra sidebar on a larger screen, but show a separate view without the sidebar on a smaller screen (they might make it possible to configure this easily in a storyboard, versus writing a bunch of code to detect the screen size and load the appropriate view programmatically). As of now, though, no such functionality exists, but that could be a potential source of the rumors regarding storyboards being useful for multiple screen sizes.